# SQL Server Profiler How to check the user Id who created SQL Server Profiler trace?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I have a profiler trace running on a sql server that is creating trace files of 200 mb each. This is eating up the drive space. Before stopping or making any change in the trace, I want to know who created this trace.

Trace Files Snapshot is attached.
[image: Trace Files]
Also, How can I reduce this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be recorded in SQLErrorlog.I just ran SQLProfiler and i got below message..

> SQL Trace ID 2 was started by login  "rgaccount"

Reducing the size can be done by reducing the number of events captured or duration